# How to train a model with loss calculated by another model in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

There are two models A and B. Model A outputs a bike deployment plan for all stations in a city, and model B takes this plan as input and gives the evaluation of each station.

Now, the model B is pretrained, and i want to use the evaluation given by model B as loss to optimize parameters of model A.

Here is the sample code.

```py
A = modelA()
B = modelB()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(A.parameters())

def my_loss(deploy):
  shape = deploy.size()
  state = torch.zeros((shape[0], shape[1], 2 + shape[1]), dtype=torch.long)

  # Notice: this step will copy deploy
  state[:, :, 2:] = torch.reshape(deploy, (shape[0], 1, shape[1]))
  state[:, :, 0] = torch.arange(0, shape[1])

  state = torch.reshape(state, (-1, 2 + shape[1]))
  eval = B(state)
  eval = torch.reshape(eval, (shape[0], shape[1]))

  return torch.mean(eval)

# Train model A
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for batch_idx, (x, useless_y) in enumerate(dataloader):
    optimizer.zero_gard()
    pred = A(x)
    loss = my_loss(pred)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

But in fact, during training, nothing happens, parameters of model A is not updated.
I also tried

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([{'params': A.parameters()}, {'params': B.parameters(), 'lr':0}])
```

and nothing happens too.

Any ideas?

Comment: After calling `backward()`, go thru `A.parameters()` and make sure they have `.grad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computational graph is cut off at `state`, so the loss does not back propagate to A.

Try;

```
state = torch.zeros((shape[0], shape[1], 2 + shape[1]), dtype=torch.long)
->
state = torch.zeros((shape[0], shape[1], 2 + shape[1]), requires_grad=True) # add requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.long may throw error
```

However, I still don't think it will work with your code.
Optional suggestion;

- I think `state_tensors` is not defined.
- In-place operation `state[:, :, 2:] =`   may not good. (In my case, this throw error) To copy tensor, `.expand()` or `.repeat()`,
  and to expand dim, `.unsqueeze()` may useful to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have no update on the parameters of `A` is because `loss`, the result of my `my_loss` is not attached to the computation graph, *i.e.* to the output of model `A`. If you have a look at your implementation, this is clearly the case:

```
    state = torch.reshape(state_tensors, (-1, 2 + shape[1]))
    eval = B(state)
    eval = torch.reshape(eval, (shape[0], shape[1]))
```

Variable `state` is defined from `state_tensors` which is not defined in your example, so it is either a typo or it is meant to be defined from `state`. Anyway, the resulting tensor `my_loss` ouputs should have a `grad_fn` attached to it. Do make sure it is the case. The last operation here is an average, so you must have something like:

```
>>> my_loss(loss)
tensor(0.7742, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

After fixing this your gradient should be able to backpropagate to the parameters of model `A`.